# Django template form within a table increasing the row height

Tags: html, css

So I'm rendering a template, including a table...and for one of the columns, the value is blank or contains a `Delete` button/form (depending on whether delete is possible).

Anyway, my issue is that if the `Delete` button is present the row height is twice that of the others, making my table look rather ugly.

```
{% if condition %}
 <td>
    <form name="input" action="./delete/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" name={{item}} value="Delete">
        <input type="hidden" name="filter_start" value={% if date1 %}{{date1}}{% endif %}>
        <input type="hidden" name="filter_end" value={% if date2 %}{{date2}}{% endif %}>
    </form>
</td>
```

{% else %}
    
    
   {% endif %}

Is there anything clearly wrong with the above? The "hidden" bits are so that I can retrieve certain 'dates' with the 'delete' button.

Comment: This is a CSS issue, not a Django issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `style="display:inline;"` on the form.